# List out all the available widget ui components name dynamically

Tags: android

I want to display, what are the available components in a list view 
dynamically 
from the package **android.widget** for android device.

That means i want to list out all the class names available in 
android.widget package at runtime.

Is there any API available to read all the **android.widget** at run time? 
Otherwise how can i achieve this? 
Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no such provision available with API.

I recommend you to build a User- Defined list to include your available components then and there it required. I hope as the way you could able to list dynamically..